# android apk non-market install update notification

Tags: android, google-play

We have users with android app installed from non-market install(manual apk install)

Also we have updated app on market place.

Will Android market send notification to user saying "new version available" on phones where app is installed manually?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. Applications which are not installed from Android Market will not get update notification from Android Market. You must implement your own update notification mechanism within your app.

Answer (score 0):

If user opens market and search for the app it shows as upgrade, market checks if the version installed on the device is same as what is there on the market. I am not sure about the automatic notification behaviour, i think it does but i saw this behaviour randomly sometimes it comes up after a hr , sometimes in a day.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Its OK if it takes time.

Comment: it is easy for you to verify urself. do you already have you app in market? Lets say version code of market app is 2, change ur apk code locally to 1 do a adb install apk.. and then go to market and see what option comes when u search for app. Make sure you sign ur local apk also with release keys.

Comment: I did that..There was no notification for 10 minutes. But as you said it takes 1 day for notification to show up, I will wait for 1 day.

Comment: Yes it shows "update" since package name is same. Question is whether it asks for update why notification.

Comment: I am not sure about when user will see the notification It was random in my case, my previous answer also says that i know for sure that user is shown as a upgrade and not a new install.

Comment: Actually I believe market not notifying is not related to whether app is installed locally or through market. In my case even for a market installed sometimes it took a day before notifying.